# Angular Slider code not changing slides

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap slider using the HTML code and CSS.
BUt the slides are not changing automatically or manually.
below is the code of slider.

```js
(function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations( elems ) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
        $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

    //Initialize carousel 
    $myCarousel.carousel();

    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');


    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });  
    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
        interval:3000,
        pause: "false"
    });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">

<div id="first-slider">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Item 1 -->
      <div class="item active slide1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
              <img style="max-width: 200px;" data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/pfmmo6qj1/window_domain.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
              <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Add images, or even your logo!</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Easily use stunning effects</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Item 2 -->
      <div class="item slide2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
              <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown"> 50 animation options A beautiful</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Create beautiful slideshows </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
              <img style="max-width: 200px;" data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/sp11uneml/rack_server_unlock.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Item 3 -->
      <div class="item slide3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
              <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Simple Bootstrap Carousel</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Bootstrap Image Carousel Slider with Animate.css</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
              <img style="max-width: 200px;" data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/eq8xvxeq5/globe_network.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Item 4 -->
      <div class="item slide4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
              <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">We are creative</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Get start your next awesome project</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
              <img style="max-width: 200px;" data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/9vf8xngel/internet_speed.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Item 4 -->

    </div>
    <!-- End Wrapper for slides-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is not enough information in order to answer. Can you provide more code or tell us what you want to do?

Comment: @user8899627 you are missing the javascript for `assets\slider.js` and there is no angular loaded, so it can't work...

Comment: @IsraGab this is the complete code of slider only... i have JS and CSS of this slider also. what else do you need pls specify??

Comment: @flob slider.js file is there on the given location and i have rechecked JS code is also written in the file, but still the code is not working fine.
And angular is also loaded that's why i am getting output of every code except the slider.

Comment: @Archit you need to add slider.js to the question and make that code working so that anyone trying to help you can reproduce the issue. Otherwise answering will be almost impossible.

Comment: @flob i have posted another question including the code of silder.JS only.
Pls search the topic mentioned below for the JS code.

Thanks.

slider code is working but its JS is not working in Angular

Comment: @Archit I added the code from slider.js, but still there is some code missing. Please edit this question and use *edit the above snippet* to edit the snippet to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your slider.js uses jQuery - thats fundamental different to using angular. You **should not mix Angularjs and jQuery** as they have very different lifecycles and it's really hard to sync those.

Comment: @flob ok... Pls suggest me the correct solution to my problem. Thanks a ton

Comment: Search for a *angular carousel* and try to integrate that :-) From thereon it might be easier. And next time post all relevant javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >

 <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"> </script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"> </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- adding  css files -->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
           <div class="container" ng-controller="CarouselCtrl">
                <div class="offsetspan6">
                     <carousel interval="myInterval">
                          <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                                <img class="image-circle" ng-src="{{slide.image}}"    style="margin:auto;"/>
                         <div class="carousel-caption">
                             <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                             <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                       </div>
                       </slide>
                </carousel>
          </div>
     </div> 
  </div>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);


// Controller  for Carousel
function CarouselCtrl($scope) {

// initializing the time Interval
  $scope.myInterval = 1000;

 // Initializing  slide rray  
$scope.slides = [
{image:'http://www.wetwebmedia.com/fwsubwebindex/Cyprinodontiform%20PIX/Platy%20PIX/Xiphophorus%20maculatusAQ%20Neon%20female.jpg',text:'Cute Fish'},

{image:'http://www.wetwebmedia.com/fwsubwebindex/Cyprinodontiform%20PIX/Platy%20PIX/Xiphophorus%20maculatusAQ%20Neon%20female.jpg',text:'Image2'},
{image:'http://www.wetwebmedia.com/fwsubwebindex/Cyprinodontiform%20PIX/Swordtail%20PIX/Xiphophorus%20helleriAQ%20Hifin%20Black%20males.jpg',text:'Image3'},
{image:'http://www.wetwebmedia.com/fwsubwebindex/Cyprinodontiform%20PIX/Platy%20PIX/Xiphophorus%20maculatusAQ%20Neon%20female.jpg',text:'Image4'}
                      ];

  var slides = $scope.slides;
  console.log(slides);

} // Controller Ends here
</script>
</html>
```